# why NPM module code get marked as a low quality code?

Tags: javascript, node.js, node-modules, npm-package

I have created a new NPM module,

When I search for it https://www.npmjs.com/search?q=mongo-strict I can see that the code quality is very low.

Can I know the reason for that?